# Represent Universal Character in Java

Tags: java, search, text

I am writing an application that searches for a specific base pair set in a long sequence. If I have a base pair sequence like this:

```
A T G C A T G A C G T A A G C T
```

I need to search it for an ambiguous set of characters.

The sequence to be found has to match the

```
n C G n A A
```

format, where the "n" represents any character. So, it would search the document to find any place where it goes

```
[any character] [C] [G] [any character] [A] [A]
```

and it would return

```
A T G C A T G [A C G T A A] G C T
```

Is there a way to represent the "n" in Java?

Comment: Take a look at regex...

Comment: you have only `n`? 
I mean `n` means any character, that's all?

Comment: Yes, ``n`` means any character

Comment: So what is the type representing your _base pair sequence_? If it is a `String`, then you can use the `.` character class documented in [java.util.regex.Pattern class' API document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef).

Comment: Yes, read the documentation for the Pattern class; if you're new to regular expressions, it will help you a great deal.

Comment: @yanana and jbkm: thank you guys! I'm reading up on the Pattern class.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  As Codebender says, regular expressions are perfect for this job:

```
public void matchBasePairSequence(String line){
    // Construct regex
    Pattern digitsPattern = Pattern.compile(".CG.AA");
    Matcher m = digitsPattern.matcher(line);

    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```